# Can't execute .pyw file when importing pyodbc?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyodbc

When I use `import pyodbc` and save my file as a .pyw (so the program skips the console and launches a GUI), nothing happens when I double-click the file.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pyodbc

root = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Enter text below:").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30).grid(column=0, row=1)  

root.mainloop()
```

However, if I comment out `import pyodbc` the program DOES run when I double-click the file.

Why would importing pyodbc prevent a .pyw from being executed on double-click? How do I work around this?

FYI, I am using Windows 7, Tkinter 8.5 and Python 3.3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run script with `import pyodbc` as `.py` in console/cmd.exe. Maybe there is some error message.

Comment: @furas Tried it and I get `ImportError:  No module named 'pyodbc'`. Why would I be able to run my script from IDLE but not elsewhere? Might it have something to do with where the modules are saved in relation to e/o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyodbc currently doesn't support Python 3.4, but does for Python 3.3 and prior. I have both 3.3 and 3.4 installed. It seems that when I execute my script from Windows desktop or explorer, it default runs with 3.4 - which of course doesn't recognize pyodbc.

I got it to work by adding the shebang statement `#!/usr/bin/python3.3` to specify which version the script is to be run on.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you can have two versions of python :)

Comment: If compatibility with Python 3.4 becomes an issue in the future then you might consider giving [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) a try. pypyodbc is being actively maintained, whereas the last update to pyodbc was over a year ago.